# index out of bounds error unity c#

Tags: indexing, touch, screen, bounds, out

The following example works well but is given error index out of bounds. Anyone know how I can fix?

another of my problem and I can not initialize the object on the touch position. thank you

```
void Update ()
    {
        goldDisplay.text = "Gold " + gold;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        int rarityRoll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, 100);
        if (rarityRoll < 99) {
            // choose something from common
            int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, commons.Length);
            // instantiate
            Instantiate (commons [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(0,0,1), transform.rotation);
            } else {
            int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, rares.Length);
            // instantiate
            Instantiate (rares [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(0,0,1), transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line get error ?

Comment: what is rares [roll].componentObjc ? you programm a Class operator ?or you want to write rares[roll].gameObject

Comment: the line of the error is that...   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

Comment: the commons [roll] .componentObjc or rares [roll] .componentObjc. basically are two lists. one contains the rare items, and other common objects.

in this case the first does a random lists. and then to choose a list, it returns to make another random objects to this list ..

Excuse my English, but I am translating on google ...

Answer (score 1):

Fix. It works without error

```
void Update ()
    {

    goldDisplay.text = "Gold " + gold;

    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touch.tapCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            int rarityRoll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, 100);
            if (rarityRoll < 99) {
                // choose something from common
                int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, commons.Length);
                // instantiate
                Instantiate (commons [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3 (0, 0, 1), transform.rotation);
            } else {
                int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, rares.Length);
                // instantiate
                Instantiate (rares [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3 (0, 0, 1), transform.rotation);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

tks

Answer (score 0):

the `Input.GetTouch(0).phase` have bug you should use `Input.touches[0].phase`
replace blow code to your code !

`void Update ()
    {
        goldDisplay.text = "Gold " + gold;`

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
    int rarityRoll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, 100);
    if (rarityRoll < 99) {
        // choose something from common
        int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, commons.Length);
        // instantiate
        Instantiate (commons [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(0,0,1), transform.rotation);
        } else {
        int roll = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, rares.Length);
        // instantiate
        Instantiate (rares [roll].componentObjc, new Vector3(0,0,1), transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I did alteration. It works exactly the same way as before. but now from a different error code on the same line. "Array index is out of range"